# Unable to run cqlsh(connection refused)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm getting a connection error "unable to connect to any server" when I run .cqlsh command from the bin directory of my node.

I'm using an edited yaml file containing only the following(rest all values present in the default yaml have been omitted) :

cluster name, num tokens,  partitioner, data file directories,  commitlog directory, commitlog sync, commitlog sync period, saved cache directory, seed provider info,  listen address and endpoint snitch.

Is this error because I've not included some important parameter in the yaml like rpc address? Please help.

OS: RHEL 6.9
Cassandra: 3.0.14

Comment: Check whether 

 Cassandra is running or not by running "netstat -an | grep 9042" 9042 is the default CQL Native Transport Port.  or If Cassandra is running then check whether you are passing right hostname. Share your logs incase if it not gets resolved.

Comment: The addresses returned from `nodetool status` should be the ones available to connect to.  Try adding one of those IPs to your cqlsh command: `$ cqlsh 1.2.3.4 -u username -p password`

Comment: nodetool status shows that cassandra is up and running in all 3 nodes.  I've configured 2 data centers,  1 has got 2 nodes in it.  But when I run cqlsh on any node(with or without their IP included), I get the same error i. e. unable to connect to any server. I also checked that 9042 port wasn't being used elsewhere.

Comment: So does this mean that it's happening because I've not included the rpc address in the yaml file? I used an edited version because I wanted only those values which I understood and gradually I wanted to bring in other variables.

Comment: Now I've added one more field in the yaml file i. e. the rpc address and I have set it's value same as the listen address.  But still, the issue does not resolve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The cassandra yaml file can have modified values, but you should not delete the rows and make your own yaml file. And yes, rpc address is needed in yaml file.
2. In writing the directories like data_file_directories, you should follow the same indentation as:

   ```
    data_file_directories - 
         /path/to/access
   ```

Cassandra is very strict at it's indentation in yaml file. I once faced an issue due to this wrong indentation in data_file_directories.

3. Finally, run ./cqlsh , provide ip_address if it is a remote server.
4. Check the nodetool status and confirm whether the node is up and normal.

Comment: nodetool status shows that cassandra is up and running in all 3 nodes.  I've configured 2 data centers,  1 has got 2 nodes in it.  But when I run cqlsh on any node(with or without their IP included), I get the same error i. e. unable to connect to any server. I also checked that 9042 port wasn't being used elsewhere.

Comment: So does this mean that it's happening because I've not included the rpc address in the yaml file? I used an edited version because I wanted only those values which I understood and gradually I wanted to bring in other variables.

Comment: Now I've added one more field in the yaml file i. e. the rpc address and I have set it's value same as the listen address.  But still, the issue does not resolve!

Comment: Add all the broadcast_rpc address and similar parameters related to it and check

Comment: Did you add start_native_transport and port columns in yaml file?

Comment: no. I've mentioned the variables present in the yaml in my question.  Only those along with rpc address are present. Nothing else.

Comment: Problem solved after adding native transport and port column.  Thanks a ton for helping

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1. Cassandra is running: `nodetool status` / `ps -elf | grep cassa`
2. Port 9042 (default for CQL) is not used by something else: `netstat -an | grep 9042`
3. Try running `` cqlsh `hostname -i` ``

Good luck.