# Order of properties in YAML

Tags: cassandra, yaml, cassandra-3.0

Does the order in which the properties are listed in the cassandra.yaml file matter? 
for e.g. can it happen that some configuration will not take effect if they are not listed in a particular order?

Comment: The order of properties should not matter. What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Yesterday, I faced an issue while starting cqlsh. Later I found out the solution(I had to include a couple of lines in the YAML). However, the problem was not sorted on my first attempt and only after I changed the order of the lines, i.e. introduced the lines in between the existing configurations rather than at the end, did the problem solve. That's why I asked this. Maybe my observation was not correct during the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have clearly explained in the first point of this answer - [Unable to run cqlsh(connection refused)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060940/unable-to-run-cqlshconnection-refused/48071599?noredirect=1)

You should not change the orders and delete the rows however you wish, because there may be some dependencies on the previous lines. If you are so willing to experiment on the yaml file, first you have to read all the bin files and conf files and figure out the mechanism, how each thing is interlinked. Then, you will get a clear idea how to exploit the full mechanism of cassandra architecture.